# Need help configuring IIS with ASP.NET in Vista Home Basic

Tags: iis

I have checked the following during turning on Windows features:

IIS,IIS Compatibility and under WWW I have checked .NET extensibility.I do not see an ASP.NET option to check.Will these be enough to have IIS running or am I missing something.

I do not see the IIS page when I type localhost in my browser.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of Vista does not support ASP on IIS.  You'll have to either install asp or upgrade your version of Vista to:

- Windows Vista Home Premium Edition
- Windows Vista Professional Edition
- Windows Vista Ultimate Edition

Comment: Ok...I have VS2008 installed...Will that be fine?

Comment: That should be fine for testing purposes.  Don't expect to host any websites on that though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set up a web server you can take a look at Microsoft's [Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx) site.

If you're a student and have the capability of proving it you can download a copy of Windows 2003 Server and use it for educational purposes.